# object[key] and Object.key behaving differently in JavaScript. why?

Tags: javascript, object

I have this code but when I run this then  "typeof object[key]" is shown as number but "typeof object.key" is shown undefined. What the reason of this strange behaviour?

```
var object = {a:3,b:4};
for (var key in object){
    console.log(typeof object[key], typeof object.key);
}
```

Comment: the correct equivalence is `object.key` === `object["key"]`. The bracket notation expects a string.

Comment: but why object.key is shown as undefined?

Comment: because you haven't assign any value to it. var object = {a:3,b:4, key: ???};

Comment: I suppose that key is var that is holding, 'a' and 'b' during iteration

Comment: you are right, key is holding, 'a' and 'b' during iteration but object.key is different variable to prove it use this var object = {a:3,b:4, key: 'the key variable of object'}; then in console.log(object[key], '-', object.key) you will see: "3 - the key variable of object" and "4 - the key variable of object"

Answer (score 4):

Within your loop, the variable `key` will evaluate to "a" and then "b".

In bracket notation, `key` is the name of that local variable and it's evaluated.

So when you evaluate `object[key]` you'll get `object["a"]` and then `object["b"]`.

However, the dot notation uses the name ("key") itself, not the value of `key`. So when you write `object.key`, you're litterally looking for the property named "key". And `object` doesn't have one, so it's `undefined`.